# Is there a tool/method to look inside in a running .NET program?

Tags: .net, code-injection

Example here:

There is a code line in my program:

`string name = "somebody"`

Is there a tool/method to know the variables and values in a running .NET program?
in above example, I expect to see:

`name = "somebody"`

**@all, I know debugger of VS, which does not solve my question,  because i can not stop the running application , but I do need to know some variable's values. I know this question is wired, but that's my question. NO stop(because my application is a service), No debug(no chance to debug), is there a way to get a variable value? without modify the source code, the application can log some important variable values if I can modify the source code. obviously, I can't**

Comment: I think you are looking for a C# profiler.

Comment: Remember that a running program is _running_. You'll have to stop it before you can look at it.

Comment: Check my post:
TRY: .NET MEMORY PROFILE 4.0 http://memprofiler.com/

Or maybe even OllyDBG i mean if you think you will get unencrypted variables you are kidding yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Many development environments (IDEs like Visual Studio etc.) can [attach to a running process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), pause execution and examine the process' memory. If that process includes debug information and the source code is available then it's a simple matter to read the value of a given variable at a point in the program. But it can also be done without debug info and source code.

This ability is actually necessary to debug applications such as web servers. And it can also be misused to glean secret or proprietary information from running applications.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio comes with it's own debugger that allows you view all variables and stacks. If you have the source code, you could simple do a breakpoint to that particular line. Unless I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

TRY:
**.NET MEMORY PROFILE 4.0**
http://memprofiler.com/

Or try..
**Simple Assembly Explorer (SAE)**
http://code.google.com/p/simple-assembly-explorer/

Or maybe even OllyDBG i mean if you think you will get unencrypted variables you are kidding yourself.

Other tools that will help you, but not as much in this question as memory profiler is....

**GrayWolf** IS 100% free Thanks to Jon Mccoy.
http://www.digitalbodyguard.com/Programs.html

GrayWolf – Is a reverse engineering tool
(focused on .NET Framework Applications)

Or for a non FREEWARE solution you can try:
Reflecter + the reflix addon
http://www.reflector.net/

And if you really really wanna stick to windows stuff you can use ***ILDASM*** from windows, download it as part of the .NET FRAMEWORK SDK. (need SDK not just VS or .NET).
[download](http://www.google.com.au/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=lad&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1680&bih=937&source=hp&q=download%20windwows%20sdk&oq=download%20windwows%20sdk&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3187l5219l0l5386l21l14l0l3l1l1l264l1310l5.4.2l11l0)

But http://memprofiler.com/ is the one you want ;)
If you really wanna get creative you could maybe even inject a custom payload into the application check dotnetasploit on digital body guards site.